# Node + Express Backend: Call third party API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have node + express backend which is called by my angular frontend (two separate domains).
In my backend, I am doing an API call to some other Third Party API.
My backend is working fine when I deploy it locally, but on deploying it to aws, the request times out (CORS Issue?). I checked issues with my deployment, and it successfully deployed, and I am able to make calls to endpoints where I am not calling the third party - API.
I also checked the API, it works when I call it manually or directly from my frontend.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Rita, it will be really helpful if we can know the API you trying to call (i.e. Is it yours or a public API), and if we can see the Error.

Comment: Added it in Daniel's answer

Comment: abc.com isn't the real API, I am presuming it can be an issue with the region of AWS and the API, or may they both have some conflict, because if it is working locally, It must work, and what of your `subnet group`? Have you configured  `outgoing security policy`?

Comment: Can you try hitting the API using curl from where your nodejs code is deployed? CORS error don't happen in the backend call. It's a browser thing.

Comment: my outgoing security policy is open for all, so not an issue. http://www1.nseindia.com//emerge/homepage/smeNormalMktStatus.json
This is the API I am hitting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a CORS issue.
The most common way to handle this is to add a `Reverse Proxy` (Nginx for example) to have a single domain that both servers the application (static files) and exposes the Backend (API).

```
                    +----------+
                    |          |
                    |  Client  |
                    |          |
                    +----+-----+
                         |
                         |  myDomain.com
                         |              
                     [INTERNET]
                         |
                         |
                         v  :80
                +--------+-------+
            /*  |                |   /api
     +----------+  Revese Proxy  +---------+
     |          |                |         |
     |          +----------------+         |
     |                                     |
     |                                     |
     | :8080                               | :3000
     |                                     |
+----+----------+                +---------+-----+
|               |                |               |
|  Angular      |                |  Backend      |
|  (webserver)  |                |  (API server) |
|               |                |               |
+---------------+                +---------------+
```

Any request to `myDomain.com` will be checked. If the path contains `/api` the request will be passed to the Backend. any other request will be passed to the webserver that contains the SPA static file.

This means that you will need to add the `/api` prefix to your client API calls (see https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)

Note: You can achieve the same using sub-domains instead of paths (`myDomain.com/api` will become `api.myDomain.com/`). You just need to be able to support it in your deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Daniel. However, the way I understood, you explained API calls from Angular to Backend. 
Scenario 1: Client calls webserver, which calls Backend for an API 1 (/api//test). The API1 simply  returns {data: success}. This is working.
Scenario 2: Client calls webserver, which calls Backend for an API 2 (/api/fail). The API2 calls a third party API (www.abc.com/api/qwerty). This is failing.
When I call www.abc.com/api/qwerty using curl, it times out.
When I deploy an app on localhost that calls www.abc.com/api/qwerty - it return data.

Comment: Think it is some server sidecontrol on the api www.abc.com/api/qwerty? Any way to resolve?

Comment: The backend can be any API (even a 3rd party). You can redirect `myDomain.com/api` to `www.abc.com/api/` using the `Reverse Proxy`.